# Native vs Hybrid mobile apps

Tags: android, ios

I apologize for the non programming specific question, but I was hoping that someone **with experience** in the matter could help shed some light.

I basically have a mobile application available on iOS, Android, Blackberry and Blackberry 10.

- The app uses locally stored databases to store (sometimes large amounts of) data.
- GPS frequently in some cases, including background GPS while the app is inactive. In fact GPS is an extremely important part of my application.
- Calendar APIs to sync app data to the device's calendar.
- Push notifications are used.
- Web services are called.

Upper management is toying with the idea of making everything hybrid, thinking long term about development costs. I completely understand their point, and for me, having everything (or some of it in the case of a hybrid) centralized on our servers will be easier (I would assume) when it comes to maintenance.

Having said that, I have some doubts about how well background processing and GPS will work in a hybrid version, if at all.

What are the common pros and cons of native and hybrid apps, especially in more complex applications? I have to write a report and submit it to my superiors outlining these points and I was just wondering if anyone **has experience (hopefully someone who has tried both native and hybrid on multiple platforms using more advances APIs)**.

**Please provide answers based on facts, references and/or specific expertise.**

Comment: Multiplatform is never completely frictionless, even using good frameworks. The time you save in rewriting two applications is used in fixing platform and configuration problems.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplatform is never completely frictionless, even using good frameworks. The time you save in rewriting two applications is used in fixing platform and configuration problems. And even there some features may be either not supported or need to be rewritten to app's specifications.

The middle ground that's acceptable would be Xamarin. It's expensive and non-native but the most frictionless experience. Following that you have C++-based frameworks, which are graphics-oriented, painful to debug specially on Android. Examples are openframework, cocos2d-x and libgdx. And at the bottom there's the javascript crap based on webviews, which just gives a painful user experience stripped of functionalities and shouldn't be used professionally, like Phonegap and Titanium.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what about background GPS?? Can this be done using hybrid?

Comment: Look into each libraries and decide for yourself. AFAIK GPS is broken in Phonegap and works fine in Xamarin but it probably falls in the category of "features may [...] need to be rewritten to app's specifications"

Answer (score 0):

I can find Cross-platform useful only for some commercial apps for presentation only purposes. It is cross-platform to one point, after that you need to add specific native addons for some features (I think the Calendar is one of those). Also, once you start with one framework it may be possible to easily move to the next version (like when the Cordova update was released for PhoneGap).

Another reason I don't like them is the fact that the apps looks the same. You get the same user experience on iOS, on Android and everything... Most users don't like this. As Android user, I almost immediately uninstall application when I see the back button in the top left corner.

Another reason - The devices does not support the same features in their webviews. Some controls will just behave not the way you expect.

Another one - not all devices uses their GPU to render the web view content. What does it means? Example - if you want your app to have rounded corners for buttons or table, this will cause the performance off the app to drop to 10-15FPS while scrolling a table. And I've seen it on high class devices (Samsung Galaxy S II when it still was the best on the market).

Conclusion: You can't have fully functioning application inside a web view control. I don't recommend the cross platform solutions at all.